# feature visualization in tsne plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I have a table [1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aRYON3_leAwBNPrLP0qU06bBIk4R1lkJ/view?usp=sharing), where each row corresponds to the feature vector of gene in particular patient. The patient IDs located in the first column (label), while gene index located in the second column (geneIndex). The rest of the columns have feature values in various dimensions (128 overall).

I was able to perform the tsne reduction on these data to 2D and label clusters according to patient IDs. Here is the code:

```
library(Rtsne)

experiment<- read.table("test.txt", header=TRUE, sep= "\t")

metadata <- data.frame(sample_id = rownames(experiment),
                       colour = experiment$label)

data <- as.matrix(experiment[,2:129])

set.seed(1)
tsne <- Rtsne(data)

df <- data.frame(x = tsne$Y[,1],
                 y = tsne$Y[,2],
                 colour = metadata$colour)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, colour = colour)) +
  geom_point()
```

However, my goal is to visualize feature vectors related to geneIndex. For example, I would like to pinpoint geneIndex "3" in red color, while the rest of the points on the plot will have grey color.

I would appreciate any suggestions!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the data, seems like there's not a lot of 3's and so if you just plot with others getting a transparent gray and selected have red.. i think it's hard to see:

```
df$geneIndex = experiment$geneIndex

plotIndex = function(data,selectedGene){
data$Gene = ifelse(data$geneIndex == selectedGene,selectedGene,"others")
ggplot(data, aes(x, y, colour = Gene))+
geom_point(alpha=0.3,size=1)+
scale_color_manual(values=c("#FF0000E6","#BEBEBE1A"))+
theme_bw()
}

plotIndex(df,3)
```

[image]

Maybe try circling the plots by plotting again, in combination with a new legend:

```
library(ggnewscale)

plotIndex = function(data,selectedGene){
  
  subdf = subset(data,geneIndex == selectedGene)

  ggplot(data, aes(x, y, colour = colour)) +
  geom_point(alpha=0.3,size=2,shape=20)+
  new_scale_color()+
  geom_point(data=subdf,
  aes(col=factor(geneIndex)),
  shape=1,stroke=0.8,size=2.1)+
  scale_color_manual("geneIndex",values="red")+
  theme_bw()
  
  
}

plotIndex(df,3)
```

[image]

You can forget about the ggnewscale library if you don't need a legend. This [package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gghighlight/vignettes/gghighlight.html) might be able to do the above too.. you needa check.

Comment: Thank you! I was wondering if there is a possibility of preserving the distribution of clusters (in my initial code), but instead of highlighting clusters in different colors - highlight only the dots corresponding to geneIndex 3.

Comment: not very clear.. I guess you want the colors but on top of it, highlight. See edit